# How to use this Git pre-commit hook

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

[Yelp detect secrets](https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets) is a system that prevents secrets from entering your code base. I would like to install [the pre-commit hook](https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets#pre-commit-hook) it provides.

I've never used Git hooks before, but all the example files I see in `.git/hooks/` are in bash, while the example given in [the readme](https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets#pre-commit-hook) of yelp is a yaml file.

They link to the [pre-commit.com](https://pre-commit.com/); "a framework for managing and maintaining multi-language pre-commit hooks".

Does this mean the yelp pre-commit hook can only be used by first installing the [pre-commit](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit) framework?

If so, I'm kind of lost in the usage of pre-commit. I've installed it and I can call it. So in an existing repo I've run `pre-commit install`. But how can I now add the yelp detect secrets pre commit hook?

Of course I've looked over the documentation on [pre-commit.com](https://pre-commit.com/), but I'm kind of lost in it.

Comment: WHat actually is your question? `pre-commit` hook is basically and arbitrary code who run before execute the commit...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to use pre-commit you'll set up a `.pre-commit-config.yaml` which includes the tools you'd like to use (such as whitespace fixers, linters, black, flake8, etc.)

detect-secrets also provides a hook using this mechanism and you can include it using [the snippet they provide](https://github.com/yelp/detect-secrets#pre-commit-hook):

```
-   repo: https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets
    rev: v0.13.0
    hooks:
    -   id: detect-secrets
        args: ['--baseline', '.secrets.baseline']
        exclude: .*/tests/.*
```

(note: I edited the snippet to use https clone urls which are much more portable)

there's also more standard tools for handling this such as bandit (which also have pre-commit integration) if you find detect-secrets to be difficult to work with

(disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit)

Comment: So the `.pre-commit-config.yaml` goes in the root of the repo?

Comment: yep it goes in the root of the repository by convention

Comment: you need at least git init . to run install-hooks

Comment: Is a way to exclude some specific lines? for example in Kubernetes very common word secretName, and I want to exclude it on a high level, not by using `#pragma: allowlist secret`

Comment: @DeamonMV this is not the issue tracker for detect-secrets